# Mapping SQL query results to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm running into some issues getting the correct JSON output from my SQL query. Essentially what I'm struggling with is getting an array of options objects as opposed to singular option objects.

```
$query = 'SELECT matchup.matchupID, matchup_option.player_name, matchup_option.player_id FROM matchup 
        INNER JOIN matchup_option
        ON matchup_option.matchupID= matchup.matchupID;';

$attachments = $db->query($query);
$data = array();
while ($attachment = $db->fetch_array($attachments)){
    $data[] = array (
        'id' => $attachment['matchupID'],
        'options' => array(
            array (
                "name" => $attachment['player_name'],
                "playerid" => $attachment['player_id']
            )
        )
    );
    //VAR_DUMP($attachment);
}
$data = array("matchup"=>$data);
print json_encode($data);
```

Gives me this output:

```
{
"matchup":[
  {
     "id":"111222",
     "options":[
        {
           "name":"111",
           "playerid":"111"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"111222",
     "options":[
        {
           "name":"222",
           "playerid":"222"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

And here's what I'm trying to get to:

```
{
"matchup":[
  {
     "id":"111222",
     "options":[
        {
           "name":"111",
           "playerid":"111"
        },
        {
           "name":"222",
           "playerid":"222"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

I'd like to follow best practices as well as structure this appropriately, if there's a better way to go about this, please let me know!

Comment: Will the *id* be same for all your rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `$attachment['matchupID']` as an array key of `$data`:

```
$data = array();
while ($attachment = $db->fetch_array($attachments)){
    if (!isset($data[$attachment['matchupID']])) {
        $data[$attachment['matchupID']] = array (
            'id' => $attachment['matchupID'],
            'options' => array()
        );
    }
    $data[$attachment['matchupID']]['options'][] = array (
        "name" => $attachment['player_name'],
        "playerid" => $attachment['player_id']
    );
}

// use `array_values` to reindex `$data`
$data = array("matchup" => array_values($data));
print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: The solution is always so damn simple! Thank you my friend.